# Customize Publish functionality in Experience Editor

Tags: sitecore-client, experience-editor, publishing

I want to add a custom condition for Publishing an item in Experience Editor Mode.
By default it uses the Publish.js and in that JS, there is function as below:

```
showPublishDialog: function(context) {
      ExperienceEditor.modifiedHandling(true, function (isOk) {
        ExperienceEditor.PipelinesUtil.initAndExecutePipeline(context.app.PublishPipeline, context);
```

What is this `context.app.PublishPipeline`, how can I abort publish pipeline based on condition?

Comment: Which version of Sitecore are you on?

Comment: using sitecore9